# Bypass the Azure AD SSO "choose an account" prompt and automatically login cookie stored user?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

We have configured our enterprise web application to be protected by Azure AD SSO. It works great. The first time the user navigates to the enterprise web application page, they are redirected to the https://login.microsoft.com login page and prompted to enter their `username@company.com` and then they are authenticated using the Windows credentials through Kerberos (or at least I think it's Kerberos. It doesn't require a password). They are now signed into our enterprise web application.

Now the user closes their browser, which closes the session with our enterprise application, then opens it again.

They go back to the enterprise web application page. It redirects to https://login.microsoft.com, and this time it remembers who they are, because it has the `username@company.com` in the "Choose an account" dialog. But it didn't automatically sign them in, making for a very unfriendly user experience.

The user now has to click on their account from the "Choose an account" screen, and there is always only just the 1 account there. It still doesn't require a password, but still it breaks the seamless flow of things.

How can we make the Azure AD SAML SSO set up so that it automatically logs in the user without having to click the account in the "Choose an account" dialog?

Comment: Nicholas, I see you got an answer from MSDN forum. Would you mind posting the answer here to help others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't getting response here so I cross-posted on MSDN (sorry). I got a prompt response here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/f9e7c013-fbdc-4bbb-9e9c-22bf187f6c79/bypass-the-azure-ad-sso-8220choose-an-account8221-prompt-and-automatically-login-cookie-stored?forum=WindowsAzureAD

> You have to pass the domain hint in order to achieve this. This
>   happening primarily because of realm discovery and domain hint will
>   help you skip this.
>
> Ref:
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-authentication-for-federated-users-portal